# Python Dataclass - getting metadata from attribute name

Tags: python-3.x, attributes, metadata, python-dataclasses

I have a Dataclass that looks like this:

```
@dataclass
class Example:
    smtng: int = field(init=True, metadata={'int_name':"Thing",'ext_name':"it"})
    smtng_else: str = field(init=True, metadata={'int_name':"other",'ext_name':"that"})
```

as you can see the metadata dict has **external** and **internal** name fields
I would like to access these through functions E.g. **get_ext_name(attribute_name)** -> which would return an attribute's name under the metadata dict "ext_name"

is there a sleek way to to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

So I found this way to do it thanks to vibhu4agarwal on GeeksForGeeks.

Adding this method to the class works:

```
def ext_name(self, attribute_name):
    return self.__dataclass_fields__[attribute_name].metadata['ext_name'])
```

if there's a better workaround I'd love to see it

here's a link to the article:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-classes-in-python-set-3-dataclass-fields/

Comment: The dataclasses library has a `fields()` method which reports back all the fields of a given dataclass or instance of that dataclass. However, it returns a tuple, not a dict, so looking up by name of the field requires iteration through that tuple, which is icky. I think this solution you gave is about as nice as you can make it.